# JSON parsing and Map in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a json response from the API like below

```
     [{name:name1,email:sample1@gmail.com,description:sss}, 
       {name:name2,email:sample2@gmail.com,description:ttt}]
```

I tried to parse it and display it in list view. But i am getting the error like the one below while map the data and the error is "_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>')".

```
    Map mappedData = jsonDecode(response);
```

Comment: try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wc8ecFSu5N8&ab_channel=MobileProgrammer

Comment: Refer my Solution and Please upvote if it works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/63462806/12037365

Answer (score 0):

first, you should build a POJO model from your JSON then you use from this code:

```
var data = jsonDecode(dataresponse);
var result = data[0] as List;
setState(() {
 List<datamodel> zonelist = result.map<datamodel>((json) => 
    datamodel.fromJson(json)).toList();
});
```