# How to fetch response that give list in api

Tags: json, flutter, api

Okay so right now i'm making small app using flutter. Right now i'm have problem with how to save this response .json from api call.

Usually i use API which give me this kind of json response:

```
{
results: [data, data]
}
```

Which i can save using

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>>
```

But now i meet api which give me this response

```
{
data,
data
}
```

How can i save this response? I am really new in flutter.

this is api json that i want to call from my github repository

```
[
  {
    "id": 361236910,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkzNjEyMzY5MTA=",
    "name": "123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E",
    "full_name": "prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E",
    "private": false,
    "owner": {
      "login": "prisma7771",
      "id": 78263670,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjc4MjYzNjcw",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/78263670?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/prisma7771",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "html_url": "https://github.com/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E",
    "description": "Prisma Putra(123190048) Praktikum SCPK E",
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E/deployments",
    "created_at": "2021-04-24T18:26:09Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-25T04:55:46Z",
    "pushed_at": "2021-04-25T04:55:44Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.com/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.com/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_KUIS_PraktikumSCPK_E",
    "homepage": null,
    "size": 467,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": "MATLAB",
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_projects": true,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "archived": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "license": null,
    "allow_forking": true,
    "is_template": false,
    "topics": [

    ],
    "visibility": "public",
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "master"
  },
  {
    "id": 381742989,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkzODE3NDI5ODk=",
    "name": "123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E",
    "full_name": "prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E",
    "private": false,
    "owner": {
      "login": "prisma7771",
      "id": 78263670,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjc4MjYzNjcw",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/78263670?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/prisma7771",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/prisma7771/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "html_url": "https://github.com/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E",
    "description": "Prisma Putra(123190048) Kelas: Prak PBO-E",
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E/deployments",
    "created_at": "2021-06-30T15:10:11Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-30T15:53:21Z",
    "pushed_at": "2021-06-30T15:53:18Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.com/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.com/prisma7771/123190048_PrismaPutra_ResponsiPBO_E",
    "homepage": null,
    "size": 35,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": "Java",
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_projects": true,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "archived": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "license": null,
    "allow_forking": true,
    "is_template": false,
    "topics": [

    ],
    "visibility": "public",
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "master"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please share your request URL or response that you want to parse?

Answer (score 0):

This answer that i found after surfing stackoverflow, successfully answer what i need. For similar question you can refer to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63462806/13456089