# type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, CartModel>' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing error :

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, CartModel>' of 'function result'

the error is here

```
void addToCart(id,price,title,urlImage){
    context.read<CartList>().addToCart(productId:id.toString(), price:price, title:title, image:urlImage);
  }
```

cart Provider

```
class CartList extends ChangeNotifier{
  Map<String, CartModel>_cart = {};

  Map get cart => _cart;

  void addToCart({required String productId,price,title,image}){
    if(_cart.containsKey(productId)){
      cart.update(productId,(value)=>
        CartModel(key: value.productId,name:value.name,
          image:value.image,
          price:value.price,
          quantity: value.quantity,
          totalPrice: value.totalPrice,
        ));
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  
}
```

here is my cart Model by the way:

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10157127)

Answer (score -1):

The error message says that `you are assigning an object of type List<String> to a variable of type Map<String, CartModel>`. For better answers I suggest you also post the content of `CardModel` and as well as the implementation of `cart.update()` function. This may people figure out the details of your problem.

You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854891/error-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-mapstring-dynamic) if it helps.

Comment: please check the last line i already posted the snippet